# DateDiff Result Set to HH:MM:SS in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I want a value returned from a `DateDiff` to format to `HH:MM:SS.`

Currently, I am using:

```
=DateDiff("S",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value).
```

How do I modify the above expression?

Answer (score 0):

```
=RIGHT("0" + CStr(DateDiff("S",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value)/3600), 2) + ":" +
 RIGHT("0" + CStr((DateDiff("S",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value)/60) Mod 60), 2) + ":" +
 RIGHT("0" + CStr(DateDiff("S",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value) Mod 60), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix:

```
=DATEDIFF("h",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value) 
 & ":" & DATEDIFF("n",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value) MOD 60 
 & ":" & DATEDIFF("s",Fields!StartDate.Value,Fields!EndDate.Value) MOD 60
```